# cs50x pset4 recover: Recovers 50 JPEGS, but half or less of the image

Tags: c, cs50, recover

My program finds all 50 jpgs. However, the images are 'incomplete'. Some are half recovered, some less than a quarter, some are just completely grey. When I opened a jpeg, that appears grey when opened, in hexadecimal it shows that there are mostly colored pixels, which makes no sense. I've attempted to find the bug from all angles.

Can anyone please help me understand why my images are 'corrupted'?

```
// 000.jpg
int j = 0;
// storing 000.jpg
char jpeg[8];
// buffer
unsigned char bf[512];
// FILE pointer
FILE *img = NULL;
// reading into memory card file
while(fread(bf, 512, 1, inptr) == 1)
{
    if (bf[0] == 0xff && bf[1] == 0xd8 && bf[2] == 0xff && (bf[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
    {
        sprintf(jpeg, "%03i.jpg", j);
        img = fopen(jpeg, "w");
        do
        {
            fwrite(bf, 512, 1, img);
            fread(bf, 512, 1, inptr);
        }
        while(bf[0] != 0xff && bf[1] != 0xd8 && bf[2] != 0xff && (bf[3] & 0xf0) != 0xe0);
        fclose(img);
        j++;
        // fread is going to read it again
        fseek(inptr, -512, SEEK_CUR);
    }
}
fclose(inptr);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're passing the 'b' flag to fopen. For example:

```
fopen(jpeg, "wb");
```

Otherwise the standard library will (often unhelpfully) automatically convert line endings for you (e.g. \n gets turned into \r\n on Windows) which when applied to binary files results in corruption.

See the [documentation for fopen](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/):

> With the mode specifiers above the file is open as a text file. In order to open a file as a binary file, a "b" character has to be included in the mode string.